# comparing values from two oracle table columns and getting starting value

Tags: oracle

I Have oracle table with data as shown below.

```
column1   column2
A1         B1
B1         C1
C1         D1
```

I need to get A1 value from D1. I have to implemet this in View. Need to traverse using as D1 as input and get C1 and get B1 from C1 and finally A1 using B1

Please help.

Comment: column 1 Column2,
A1 B1,
B1 C1,
C1 D1

Comment: What do you expect with input `C1` or `B1`? In other words , do you always perform two joins from column1 to column2?

Comment: i need to get A1 when i input D1.  i have upto 5 values linked like shown above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of view you are looking to create; if you are thinking of passing 'A1' as an input to the view, there is no such thing in Oracle as far as I know, you would need to use a cursor for that.

The following SELECT statement can be used as an inline view (a subquery) and you **can** make the `'D1'` value at the end of it into a bind variable if needed.

```
select     column1
from       test_data
where      connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by column2 = prior column1
start with column2 = 'D1'
;
```